# Use Same Function of R Package in New Package

Tags: r, function, package

I want to use a function from another R package in my own R package. I have an idea of `Imports` but it helps to calculate a specific part of the function, i.e. in package `ks` the function `Hpi` is exactly the same as the function of `KernSmooth`. I want code that directly calls a function from another package and proceeds.

Comment: Maybe https://r-pkgs.org/r.html#aliasing-a-function could help?